# Meteor Moment-Helpers not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

im trying to setup a clock on my website, and I saw the moment-helpers package, so installed the moment + the moment helpers one, when i use moment(); in the console, it shows the correct date and time, when i add {{moNow}} there is no problem either, problem is when I use {{moFormat moNow 'HH:mm:ss'}}, nothing shows up! Am i missing something?
Also, how can I debug those kind of problems? I see myself searching a lot and then asking questions on forums etc because I can't seem to know the problem, most of the times for stupid things.. lol
Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you paste more of your template code?

Comment: its just a simple bootstrap nav:
https://jsfiddle.net/vat2vy74/

Comment: this works fine:  [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/zdXnkvNszBBbAMfmh/moment)

Comment: this is really weird, I mean it works in that browser version, but not on my project files although i have all the same packages and everything, is it because im using a route? ill upload it later for you guys to check it out, thanks!

Comment: Ok i got it, I even downgraded my meteor version to see if that was the problem, after I added meteor-platform package it worked just fine..